# Insert default value if custom post type field is empty

Tags: wordpress, admin, default

In my custom post type, if one of the fields are left blank, how can I insert a default value before it is saved to the db? This happens after the user clicks on **Publish** before I insert the default value so it all happens behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pre_post_update` or `save_post` hook : 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Or instead saving this default value in db, you can simply display it when the field is blank.

Comment: It's good that you mentioned `pre_post_update` since it crossed my mind. Will give it a shot and let you know if it worked.